# how to replace a a double back slashes in a string with a single back slash in a ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

How do I replace a double backslash in a string with a single backslash?

I was trying to do it with `"\\a\\b\\c".gsub!("\\\\","\\")`, but that is not working.

Comment: Best tags I ever saw on a question. You might want to use the tags 'ruby' and 'string' instead to address ruby developers.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, since I know nothing about ruby:

might it be that the back slash has a special meaning inside strings ? Have a try with this:

```
"\a\b\c".gsub!("\\\\","\\")
```

Comment: I have tried something like this, 
`code`
irb(main):001:0> a="\\ha\\ha"
=> "\\ha\\ha"
irb(main):002:0> m=a.gsub("\\","\\")
=> "\\ha\\ha"
irb(main):003:0> puts m
\ha\ha
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts m.class
String
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts m.length
6
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> puts a.length
6
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> puts a
\ha\ha
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> n=a.gsub("\\","")
=> "haha"
irb(main):009:0> puts n
haha
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> puts n.length
4
=> nil
irb(main):011:0> n.inspect
=> "\"haha\""
irb(main):012:0> m.inspect
=> "\"\\\\ha\\\\ha\""
irb(main):013:0> a.inspect
=> "\"\\\\ha\\\\ha\""

Answer (score 0):

[in ruby strings the backslash is the special first char to start an "escape sequence"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings), therefore:

`\\ - means single backslash`

To better understand this example may help:

```
  >> s = "\\ha"
  => "\\ha"
  >> s.split(//)
  => ["\\", "h", "a"]
```

as you can see you have only 3 char, the first is a single backslash, represented by the escape sequence `\\`

#### now we substitute the single backslash with double backslash

```
   >> s.gsub!("\\","\\\\\\")
   => "\\\\ha"
   >> s.split(//)
   => ["\\", "\\", "h", "a"]
```

our string is now of 4 char the first and the second are backslash.

#### now we come back to the original string by replacing double backslash with a single backslash

```
   >> s.gsub!("\\\\","\\")
   => "\\ha" 
   >> s.split(//)
   => ["\\", "h", "a"]
```

the above examples are tested using: ruby 1.8.7, irb 0.9.5